# Swiffy: Convert from Flash to HTML5: Input text is not supported

Tags: html, flash

We are using the [swiffy converter](https://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/) to convert our [math flash programs](http://www.matheretter.de/mathe-programme) to HTML5.

Problem is, a lot of our programs have input fields that are not converted by Swiffy. The error message is:

`Input text is not supported. (2 occurrences)`

Now we try to find a workaround to setup things in Flash so that the conversion works including the input fields.

Has anyone found a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might do is to convert the input text fields to dynamic text fields, then create buttons that fill out these text fields. I tried it and it worked. Considering it is a math app, you might want to create a keypad that sends the numbers to these text fields and a clear button to allow users to delete incorrect entries. It might seem like a lot of work for a simple event, but this is only until Swiffy converts input text
Best wishes

```
//assuming you have a dynamic text field on stage named 'inputIN_txt' and a button named 'inputBtn'

inputBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onInputData)
function onInputData(e:Event): void{
inputIN_txt.text="Hello, Swiffy"
}
```